# How AngularJS works?

Tags: angularjs

I am practicing with AngularJS and I want to understand how AngularJS works.

If we try following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-controller="personController">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>

<script>
function personController($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John",
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
alert('Angular');
}
alert('JS');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

in http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_controller

Then first we get "JS" alert and we can see expression for Full Name still not processed.
If we click OK for alert box then second alert for "Angular" appears and Full Name still to be processed.
But as soon as we click on OK for the second alert box Full Name expression gets processed immediately.

My question is how flow of code goes back to `$scope.firstName = "John"` and `$scope.lastName = "Doe";` after `alert('Angular');` inside the controller.

Comment: Please try to make up a better name for your question than "How AngularJS works".

Comment: Also, try reading [some documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) to find out when exactly are your controller constructors called.

Answer (score 2):

Template update happens in the first digest cycle after the values have been changed.

The alert happens in the same cycle, so the scope variables are updated, but the template isn't because we're still inside the function block (it wouldn't make sense to try and update external stuff before the function is fully evaluated). And alert is blocking the further execution of the script until it's closed, so that's why it seems like a long time before the template is updated, while actually it's just the very next step after the function call.

> My question is how flow of code goes back to $scope.firstName = "John" and $scope.lastName = "Doe"; after alert('Angular'); inside a javascript function.

The flow never "goes back" but only updates the template with the changed values of scope variables. As I said, holding the alert box open just prevents the further execution of the code and as soon as you close it, the function call ends, the watchers fire up a new digest cycle and the template is updated.